# Lighting preview does not work in Blender 2.78?

Tags: 3d-view, opengl

It seems that the OpenGL light previews are not available in the material preview mode (<strike>neither cycles nor internal</strike> edit: only in cycles) with the most recent blender version.
Was this intended or is it a glitch on my side? I really miss this feature.

edit: here is an example of what I Mean:
[image: 1]]

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently supported, it's a known limitation of the current system.

Cycles OpenGL material preview has vey limited functionality, [until recently (before 2.78)](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.78/Viewport) it didn't even have proper texture preview

It is currently planned to be substancially improved for Blender 2.8 project with a new [viewport rendering](https://code.blender.org/2016/09/blender-2-8-viewport-development) system [supporting PBR](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?390592-Blender-PBR-viewport-Branch-v0-2) and improved performance

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, it is strange that this functionality has vanished (it used to work in the previous version). I will keep waiting for 2.8 then.

Comment: It didn't vanish, it just never existed in the first place